# How to plot two sets of data on one ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting

I have two sets of x,y coordinates, and want to plot them both on the same graph. With one set,

List1 $= \{ \{ x_1, y_1 \}, \{ x_2, y_2 \},\{ x_3, y_3 \}, \cdots \}$

I can use `ListLinePlot[List1]`.

But with a second list,

List2 $= \{ \{ u_1, v_1 \}, \{ u_2, v_2 \},\{ u_3, v_3 \}, \cdots \}$

I assumed I'd be able to use something like `ListLinePlot[List1,List2]`, but this seems reserved for when the lists have only one of the coordinates: $\{ x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots\}$.

The data in `List1` has to be connected via a line, as does the data in `List2`, but they mustn't be joined together (i.e. I can't amalgamate them into one list). Anyone know how I can plot both sets on the same graph?

Comment: The answer is the third syntax form on the [ListLinePlot doc page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListLinePlot.html). If you have questions in the future, could you please check the reference pages first?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I did! I made the mistake of thinking the curly brackets outside each list $\{ \{ x_1, y_1 \}, \cdots \}$ were the same curly brackets as in the 3rd form of ListLinePlot in the documentation, so I was short of the outside set of brackets.

Comment: Yeah, that is quite understandable. The docs have the habit of summarizing earlier syntax constructions that are being reused in forms later on into a single word (not formally defined). So, {{x1,y1},⋯} becomes list1. It happens all the time and it takes some getting used to it. Apologies if I sounded rude.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries No worries, thank for your comment. Hopefully I'll get used to it soon :o)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of `ListLinePlot[ list1, list2 ]` use `ListLinePlot[ {list1, list2} ]`.

Comment: Awesome - thanks. Seems so obvious now!

Comment: @Calvin To the best of my knowledge, every plotting function operates that way. So, if you need to plot multiple things on a single plot, just wrap them in a list.

Comment: One exception is the `PairedXXXX` set of functions.  Although in that case it perhaps depends on your interpretation of "single plot".

Answer (score 3):

Or

```
p1=ListLinePlot[list1, PlotStyle -> {DotDashed, Thick}, PlotLegends -> {"list1"}];
p2=ListLinePlot[list2, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black}, PlotLegends -> {"list2"}];
Show[p1,p2]
```